# Access key value from Web.config in Razor View-MVC3 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I access a key value from web.config in my Razor view.

This is in my `web.config` in the Web Project root level.

```
 <appSettings>
   <add key="myKey" value="MyValue"/>
</appSettings>
```

I want to have to use the key in my Razor view.

Thank you.

Comment: @sathish Kumar: I thought it is bit different in MVC, so I had to ask in here, So it very worst  question you voted it down. Remember you have alos started your career as begineer, be polite and respect others. I could not find this kind of question in google search.. Razor is new..

Comment: Sorry about that.As per the stackoverflow FAQ i did.For this question i had many results from google.If i did anything wrong once again sorry.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

```
@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]
```

Comment: Have a look at Peter's answer, since in this one you have to add reference ConfigurationManager

Answer (score 258):

The preferred method is actually:

```
@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]
```

It also doesn't need a reference to the ConfigurationManager assembly, it's already in System.Web.

Comment: What's the difference between @Anwar's answer and yours? Besides the naming ;)

Comment: System.Configuration might need to be referenced separately if it's not used elsewhere in your project, but System.Web is already referenced in an MVC project.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a real world example with the use of non-minified versus minified assets in your layout.

Web.Config

```
<appSettings>

   <add key="Environment" value="Dev" />

 </appSettings>
```

Razor Template - use that var above like this:

```
@if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"] == "Dev")
{    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/theme.css" )">    

}else{        

   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/blue_theme.min.css" )">    

}
```

Comment: Even if it's nice with real life examples, using minification that way with .net MVC is a shame. Have a look at bundling http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 2):

FOR MVC

-- WEB.CONFIG CODE IN APP SETTING --
`<add key="PhaseLevel" value="1" />`

-- ON VIEWS suppose you want to show or hide something based on web.config Value--

-- WRITE THIS ON TOP OF YOUR PAGE--
`@{
    var phase = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhaseLevel"].ToString();
}`

-- USE ABOVE VALUE WHERE YOU WANT TO SHOW OR HIDE.

`@if (phase != "1")
{
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_LeftSideBarPartial.cshtml")
}`